# SharePoint online solution licensing

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, licensing, licence

We are working on solution which we belive could be useful for organizations using SharePoint. We designed and implemented solution so it can be used in sharepoint online. Since we want to be selling our product, we should work with some kind of an licensing solution/mechanism.

Have you ever done something similar for sandboxed solutions and could point directions or say what might work and what not?

Comment: Have you thought about making this an APP and using the marketplace to manage it?

Comment: We could consider that - where I can find guidelines for adding solution into o365 marketplace?

Answer (score 1):

There are two or three most widespread licensing models for SharePoint components: per server, per Farm, per site collection. At [ArtfulBits](http://www.artfulbits.com/purchase/#Sharepoint_1) we've used to "per Farm" licensing model (for on-premise solutions) that doesn't limit the number of WFE servers within the licensed Farm.
   However, for the sandboxed solutions seems to be possible on "per site collection" licensing model.
   You have also think over the full cycle of licensing and consider how it will work in the cases like license reassignment in different situations, trial licensing, licensing for extended development needs, technical support an etc. In other words, you have to build the entire licensing model, that takes into account even the smallest issues, before you begin to sell your components.